# Developing proprietary open source using Team foundation server

Tags: tfs, open-source

In our work place we use Team foundation server as the main server used for source control, work tracking, build server etc. 
We develop in house software with many teams working on different projects.
Sometimes we develop applications or libraries which can and should be shared in our company including the ability to have more than one team contributing.  Unfortunately due to nature of the applications being developed they cannot be shared outside our company. 
I would like to know if tfs can help in that respect or do I need to add other tools. 
For instance if our teams work in different areas or team projects how can open source projects be shared without risking editing permissions or such. How can projects be shared, cataloged, published? 
How can issues be published for the project?   How can pull request be done as they are done in github?

Answer (score 0):

Share projects or source code in TFS is accomplished mostly through a combination of using the Area hierarchy and Teams functionality.

Then we can use the Area field to filter all reports and queries.  Each Team is tied to the related Area and is used to provide each Team/Sub-Project with it’s own Product Backlog.  And **Security can be granted based** on Area and/or Source Control Path.

---

**Update**

Permission is a very important concept in TFS. The simplest and safe way is using permission to restrict and help other team contributing to the share projects. One main team/group which have all permissions for the contributing to the share project.

Most of the teams/groups which have visibility into the share projects. They need to [create pull requests](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/pull-requests) to review and merge code in  project. Pull requests let your team **give feedback on changes in feature branches before merging the code into the master branch**. Reviewers can step through the proposed changes, leave comments, and vote to approve or reject the code. The same thing as GitHub.

And many times a request or issue fix will come from the share project managers , but they are not sure what team or project it should be assigned to. Then you could use share product backlog items (pbi, or user story if you are using agile template) across team projects within TFS. Since you are using a multiple team strategy under a single team project. You could collect the pbi’s and place them in an oversight queue that will be reviewed by either an individual or committee. Then these pbi’s will get moved as they get assigned to teams and projects. However, you also need to setup security in way so that the individual teams don’t have permissions to get in and monkey around with other teams backlog, queries, or code.

Otherwise, there are no built-in share project process or tool inside TFS, if you really need this, could add a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

Comment: As mentioned in my question, our code cannot be accessed outside our company. Furthermore we cannot use any cloud based tools for our development and we don't actually use tfvc but git

Comment: @CaptainNemo Have update my reply for your reference.